# ClickOnce Url Parameters are missing

Tags: c#, .net, url, query-string, clickonce

I have a ***ClickOnce application*** that I deploy so it can be called using a URL to a `.application` file.

I'm trying to pass arguments using `queryString` type parameters (`?arg1=foo&arg2=bar`).

I cannot make this work. Tried all sorts of things and still no luck retrieving them on the client app side.

This is what I tried so far :

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]
```

and also the older way which I believe is

```
 ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri
```

and none allowed me to get to the parameters (mostly it just gives me back `null`)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...!

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I wonder if there is something on IIS that needs to be set so that it modifies the return .application file.  That's just a static file.  I have no idea how passing parameters to the URL (which is just an HTTP GET on a static file) actually ends up passing URL parameters to the ClickOnce app, unless it's specific to launching it in IE (I'm using Chrome).

Comment: From what you say, it's not clear if you published application to a web server (like IIS) or just file share. Arguments via ActivationUri can be passed only if hosting at web server.

Answer (score 2):

try this functions:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// parse name=value pairs from parameter string
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static string[] GetQueryStringParameters()
        {
            string query = string.Empty;
            if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
            {
                if (ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri != null)
                    query = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
                        ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.ActivationUri.Query);
            }
            else
            {
                var _params = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
                if (_params.Length > 1)
                    query = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(_params[1]);
            }

            string[] arguments = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) && query.StartsWith("?")) 
            {
                arguments = query.Substring(1).Split('&'); 
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query) && (arguments == null || arguments.Length == 0))
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format(
                        @"exception while decoding params: ""{0}"" ", query));

            return arguments;
        }


    /// <summary>
    /// decode "name"="value" pairs into hashtable
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Hashtable _decodeParams(ICollection<string> pParams)
    {
        var result = new Hashtable(pParams.Count);
        foreach (var t in pParams)
        {
            string[] sParamAndValue = t.Split('=');
            if (sParamAndValue.Length > 1)
            {
                result.Add(sParamAndValue[0], sParamAndValue[1]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

usage:

```
var allParams = new Hashtable();
var stringParams = GetQueryStringParameters();
if (stringParams != null)
    allParams = _decodeParams(stringParams);
```

also you should enable option **Allow URL parameters to be passed to application** before deploying you application

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `mageui.exe` and check if url parameters are allowed.

Bellow screen shows this option http://dontpaniclabs.blob.core.windows.net/public-images/dplblog/clickonce%20publish19.png

Comment: What mechanism is used to pass the query parameters?  The .application file is just a static file served by IIS (or another HTTP server) and a normal link to it just performs an HTTP GET.  Passing query parameters to the HTTP GET won't alter the .application file returned so how do those parameters get passed to the launched application since basically that .application file is just ShellExecute'd to launch the application.

Comment: In your exe you can parse them

Comment: Right, I was wondering how to actually pass them to the EXE. Other research looks like this is only.possible with IE and with custom setup.exe's.